# checksum_agg and checksum in Oracle11g and Postgres 9.2.4

Tags: postgresql, oracle11g, checksum

This link https://sqlundercover.com/2018/12/18/quickly-compare-data-in-two-tables-using-checksum-and-checksum_agg/ gives the use of `checksum_agg` and `checksum` functions for easy validation of table data. I gather these are supported in MS SQL server. Is there any equivalent implementation of these functions in Oracle11g and Postgres 9.2.4? I did some searches and couldn't find any ready-made solution. Please help!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: No, they do not appear to be supported.